# Nextjs getInitialProps not working on page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, server-side, server-side-rendering

I have an issue which I need help on. I currently have a page in which I am fetching my data inside the `getInitialProps`, and it works when navigating using `Link` or `Router.push`. But it wouldn't fetch when I reload or share the URL of the page to my friends.

So the question is, is it best practice for SEO if I fetch the data in the `useEffect hook` or should I just add add `useEffect hook` and make it to fetch on the condition that the resource is undefined which also solves the problem?

Below is my `getInitialProps`

```js
Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx: NextPageContext) => {
  const {
    query: { slug }, reduxStore,
  } = ctx;
  const { token } = nextCookies(ctx);
  try {
    await reduxStore.dispatch(fetchBookChapter(`${baseUrl}/chapters/${slug}`, token));
    return { token };
  } catch (error) {
    return redirectOnError(ctx);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Please share the code, so that we can see where you are having the mistake.

Comment: I just added the code

Answer (score 0):

If getInitialProps uses data from the client side, reload does not.

Comment: Can you backup your answer please?